# Center html/css nav bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I am learning how to work with basic html code and page layouts. I have the following html and css code. I want the nav bar to be aligned centered on the top of the page. If I run it now, it looks close to what I want, but it is stuck to the left.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a>A</a></li>
            <li><a>B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>BA</a></li>
                    <li><a>BB</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>C</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>CA</a></li>
                    <li><a>CB</a></li>
                    <li><a>CC</a></li>
                    <li><a>CD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>D<a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: url('nature.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white; 
}

.nav ul{
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: green; 
}

.nav ul li ul li{
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

I tried changing the display and float values based on various articles, but i did not find anything that worked. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really sweet solution with margin auto. In your css file, just add these two properties to .nav class

```
.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

it will make the width of your nav div to just fit content and then position it to center because of that auto margin. Cheers

Comment: anytime brother, if you can make the question answered, that would help me:)

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
 .nav ul li{ float: left; }
```

use

```
 .nav ul li{ display: inline-block; }
```

and add

```
 .nav{ text-align: center; }
```